# Typescript returns error when a function type is FunctionalComponent, but not for arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Below is the example:

```
function RoundButton(): React.FC {
  return <div>"hello world"</div>;
}
```

gives an error:

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.   Type
> 'Element'provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?:
> ReactNode;}, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)

but the code below:

```
const RoundButton: React.FC = () => {
      return <div>"hello world"</div>;
    }
```

does not. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first case, you're saying what the function *returns*, but in the second case you're saying what the function *is*.

The second one is correct. `React.FC` is a function type. Your second block says your function is a `React.FC`, which means it accepts `props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any` and returns `ReactElement<any, any> | null`.

If you wanted to use `function` syntax rather than arrow syntax, you could write it as:

```typescript
const RoundButton: React.FC = function() {
    return <div>"hello world"</div>;
};
```

...or if you really want a function *declaration* rather than a function expression, since we know `React.FC` (like all component functions) has only a single parameter, we can use the [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility types:

```typescript
function RoundButton2(props: Parameters<React.FC>[0]): ReturnType<React.FC> {
    return <div>"hello world"</div>;
}
```